# Why isn't my view redirecting to a controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a html form inside one of my views that is supposed to get an image the user uploads and save it, the form is below:

```
<form class="col-lg-12" action="/banner/store/">
```

The form itself is quite large, but later on there's a  to end it. It was supposed to redirect me to the banner/store where my Banner controller have a dd() function so I can confirm everything is okay. But instead, I get a blank white screen and the url goes banner/store/?.

The routes to the BannerController seems to be correct since banner/create works, the problem is when I go from create to store, but anyways, here's how I set the Routes:

```
Route::resource('banner', 'BannerController');
```

Any ideas why my banner/store won't work? And why is there a question mark on the end of the url? Sorry if this may be a dumb error, I'm still learning coding.

Comment: Please share more code

Comment: Resource routing doesn't create any route with `store` in the URI   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your action is is wrong. When you use the `resource` static method then the store-url is the same as the GET url.

You can achive your goal with:

```html
<form class="col-lg-12" action="{{ route('banner.store') }}" method="POST">
```

See more information in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

When you updating your banner, you can't use the browser native form with `PUT`.
See in this [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing) how laravel will handle that for you.